# How to Enable Advanced Search While Creating Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have create custom attribute programatically,  these are the fields,

```
  $eavSetup->addAttribute(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'myattribute',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'group' => 'Product Details',/* Group name in which you want to display your custom attribute */
            'type' => 'text',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
            'attribute_set' =>  'myattribute',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Address', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'class' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false
        ]
    );
```

I need to enable Advanced Search while creating Custom Attribute in programatically, if i set  **'searchable' => true'** only enable **Use in Search** field, but not enable **Visible in Advanced search**.

Reference:

[image]

Suggest me How to enable this programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below line do the trick of enable **Visible in Advanced search**

```
'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
```

Comment: Magento is crap buddy, column name in table is 'is_visible_in_advanced_search' and when you create attribute you need to pass 'visible_in_advanced_search', Not Fair!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'lenscolor',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'group' => 'Color Details',
            'type' => 'text',
            'attribute_set' =>  'mycolor',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Lens Color', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'class' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => true  /* set true for enable advanced search while creating custom attribute */

        ]
    );
```